# MIUI ROM English Version for Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: rom

[MIUI ROM](http://www.miui.com) is available in Chinese for [Samsung Galaxy S](http://www.miui.com/shuaji-70.html). (There is an [english site](https://en.miui.com) as well, but it doesn't list Galaxy S) After the install, according to the docs, I get this on the screen:

[image: MIUI ROM]
<sub>(source: [miui.com](http://www.miui.com/static/article/zhinan_sus.jpg?1))</sub>

Will I be able to change the language to English and continue to use the phone without any chinese interaction or should I use a custom mod?

Comment: Which "Samsung Galaxy S" exactly?

Comment: I think I got it. http://miui.us

Answer (score 2):

The base MIUI is quite closed source and opaque (there was some brouhaha on XDA about it) I'm sure. There are several spin-offs and/or AOSP merges in different languages on XDA.

These are specific links to current MIUI ROMs (current as at 29 Aug 2011)

- I9000: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1118682
- SGS2: http://www.galnetmiui.co.uk

However, I'd suggest you monitor the [relevant device forum at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) and see what's out there. Versions change, ROMs come and go, threads are closed/new ones opened etc so *the two links above may not be reliable over time*

I have a HTC Desire: there were half a dozen MIUI ROMs for this a few months ago. YMMV of course

Edit:

Note also that ROM developers are leaving XDA because of the noise and stupid users. Hence the galtnet MIUI link (which I got from XDA). So you may find less info than you expect on XDA

You said MIUI but I can recommend [Oxygen](http://forum.oxygen.im/index.php) for the SGS2 (I use this on my Desire)